# gnu make - determine if stdout is terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile

Trying to do:

```
help:
    @echo "you must $(call red_text,clean)"
```

where red_text is defined as

```
red_text = $(shell tput setaf 1; echo -n "$1"; tput sgr0)
```

This prints "you must clean", where word "clean" is printed in red.

The problem is when the output of make is piped (e.g. to less). 
In this case I should not use colors, but rather print the $1.

I need to update `red_text` to handle the case. For that I thought I can use something like `$(shell [ -t 1 ] ..)` but the problem is that the *stdout* of `$(shell)` is never a terminal.

How can I change `red` to handle the case when *stdout* is not to a terminal?

Comment: check the exit status of `tty` command?

Comment: @anishsane This will have same problem as checking [ -t 1 ]

Comment: This problem is probably easier to solve in your build server: `FANCY ?= 1` and then call `FANCY=0 make` when non-color output is desired.

Comment: @thiton It's better make will handle it by itself, instead of education user :)

Comment: Is it too much to ask your user to use `less -r`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell It could be grep, or redirect to file or what ever. This should be solved by makefile itself

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, there is no way to test from `$(shell ...)` whether the output is a standard terminal or a pipe / file. There are however a few things we can do, each with their own pros/cons.

**Detect TTY in a custom `make` script**

We simply write a simple shell script that intercepts the call to the native `make`, detects the TTY, and defines a variable appropriately. The main advantages of this solution:

- simplicity,
- works for `echo`, `$(info ...)` and alike, `$(shell ...)` commands,
- no modification required in the recipes,
- no extra process spawned at each echo, which on some platform can be quite slow (eg. Cygwin).

```
ifdef IS_TTY
# DO NOT ADD TRAILING COMMENTS OR THIS WILL FAIL BECAUSE OF TRAILING SPACES
ESC := $(shell printf '\e')
R := $(ESC)[31m
Z := $(ESC)[0;0m
endif

$(info [info  ] $Rred$Z black)
$(shell echo >&2 "[shell ] $Rred$Z black")
if_fancy:
    @echo "[recipe] $Rred$Z black"
```

Example of custom make script to add in path (eg. `/usr/local/bin/make`):

```sh
#! /bin/bash

[ -t 1 ] && IS_TTY=1 || IS_TTY=0
exec /usr/bin/make IS_TTY=$IS_TTY "$@"
```

This method provides the expected output in all these cases

```sh
make                  # Colored
make >&2              # Colored
make | cat            # NOT colored
make >tmp && cat tmp  # NOT colored
```

**Detect in recipe and call the Makefile recursively**

In some cases, it might not be possible to intercept the call to make or replace it with a custom script. In this solution, we fix that limitation by detecting the TTY in a first pass, and then calling the same Makefile recursively with the appropriate variable set.

```
ifndef IS_TTY
.SILENT:
%:
    @[ -t 1 ] && IS_TTY=1 || IS_TTY=0; $(MAKE) IS_TTY=$$IS_TTY "$@"
xyz:
    @[ -t 1 ] && IS_TTY=1 || IS_TTY=0; $(MAKE) IS_TTY=$$IS_TTY
else

ifeq ($(IS_TTY),1)
# DO NOT ADD TRAILING COMMENTS OR THIS WILL FAIL BECAUSE OF TRAILING SPACES
ESC := $(shell printf '\e')
R := $(ESC)[31m
Z := $(ESC)[0;0m
endif

$(info [info  ] $Rred$Z black)
$(shell echo >&2 "[shell ] $Rred$Z black")
recursive:
    @echo "[recipe] $Rred$Z black"

endif
```

The disadvantage of this method is that it adds quite some garbage in the Makefile. Dealing with recursion may be tricky. In the example above, I only applied some basic recursive mechanism that should work when `make` is called with or without a target, and which should also propagate variables. Extending this would be the subject of another question ;-)

**Strip the escape sequences at each echo**

We test at each echo command whether the output is a TTY, and we strip the escape sequences if not so (using https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream). To reduce the spam on the line, we use a make variable `$(STRIPESC)`. The solution is quite simple, but it only works for `echo` command, and spawns an extra process at each echo. It also requires to edit every recipe with an echo.

```
# DO NOT ADD TRAILING COMMENTS OR THIS WILL FAIL BECAUSE OF TRAILING SPACES
ESC := $(shell printf '\e')
R := $(ESC)[31m
Z := $(ESC)[0;0m
STRIPESC:=( [ -t 1 ] && cat || sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' )

# $(info ...) not supported
# $(shell echo >&2 ...) not supported
if_tty:
  @echo "[recipe] $Rred$Z black" | $(STRIPESC)
```

**Use an external echo command to strip escape sequences**

This is similar to the solution above except that the syntax is a bit more lightweight. The pros/cons are the same. Also, in the example below, I generate the external echo in the makefile itself. In a standard build, you would provide this command as an external tool in some standard path.

```
# DO NOT ADD TRAILING COMMENTS OR THIS WILL FAIL BECAUSE OF TRAILING SPACES
ESC := $(shell printf '\e')
R := $(ESC)[31m
Z := $(ESC)[0;0m

$(shell echo "#! /bin/bash" > echotty)
$(shell echo '[ -t 1 ] && echo "$$@" || echo "$$@" | sed "s/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g"' >> echotty)
$(shell chmod a+x echotty)

# $(info ...)
# $(shell echo >&2 ...)
.PHONY: echotty
echotty:
  @./echotty "[recipe] $Rred$Z black"
```

Answer (score 0):

@fuujuhi already provided a good answer if you care about reliability, but all of his solutions are quite complex. If you need a quick 'n dirty solution, I found this to work quite reliably (although it depends on the implementation of make):

```
red_text = $(shell [ -c /proc/$$PPID/fd/1 ] && (tput setaf 1; echo -n "$1"; tput sgr0) || echo -n "$1")
```

Just be aware that it may still detect a tty if you pipe into a character device like `/dev/null`. This may not be an issue for color output, but in other cases it could be.

Comment: Inspired by @Joja's solution, I've come up with this:
`OUTPUT := $(shell [ -t 1 ] > /proc/$${PPID}/fd/1 && echo terminal || echo pipe)` .

It should expand to `terminal` if the output is a terminal, or `pipe` otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

```
if test -t 1
then
    echo terminal
else
    echo file
fi
```

Comment: -1: The OP already stated why [ -t 1 ] doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @thiton, this: 
`help:`<newline+tab>
    `if test -t 1; then    echo terminal; else     echo file; fi`
works for me.

Comment: @Ben: Does `$(shell if [ -t 1 ]; then echo terminal; fi)` also work? The OP stated that it doesn't, and I strongly suspect he is right.

Answer (score -3):

In the spirit of **Perfection is reached not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away (Antoine de Saint Exupery)**, solve the problem by *not using color in the first place!* Really. It <strike>sucks</strike> has inherent problems. You make assumptions about terminals that will be wrong for some poor user some fine day. You run into this interactive terminal issue. You spend time solving a problem that could be better spent programming cool functionality instead of *eye candy*. You please the wrong group of people, namely, the chromatically addicted, and disregard the chromatically challenged, like red/green blind users (of which there are more than you and I estimate).

Comment: A personal opinion is not an answer. Colours in themselves aren't bad - your change to state they have '_inherent problems_' is better - but some things are Just Easier with colours enabled, such as fast visual processing of gcc output (*particularly* with heavy usage of C++ templates).

Of course it's a personal choice, and of course there will be differences in colour perception within a user base, but '_eye candy_' is dismissive of the benefits, and '_You please the wrong group of people_' is polarising and could be seen as offensive tbh.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich If someone asks "How do I commit suicide?" would do the same nit-picking when I answered "Let's solve your problem by looking at it from a completely different angle and it may become a non-issue?" I teach people to stand back, think outside the box, make them realize their X-Y-problem. Sadly, no good dead goes unpunished.

Comment: @Jens: No offense, but you didn't answer the question, you commented on it. Comments are perfectly ok and no one ever said comments must not be helpful. But they don't belong into that text area labeled "Your answer"...